# Implementation of quantum Hadamard gate using electron spins?

Tags: quantum-gate, hadamard, superposition

The Hadamard gate performs the following operation on an incoming electron spin:

[image]

What is a realistic laboratory way of implementing a Hadamard gate that will change a known electron spin into one with an equal superposition of UP and DOWN spin?

Answer (score 2):

You almost always drive the desired electron spin transition with microwaves at a certain power for a certain period of time.

For example, if you were working on nitrogen vacancy centers in diamond, you'd first calibrate by finding the transition frequency (usually around 2.5-3GHz), then you'd drive that transition with a certain microwave power to determine the Rabi frequency of that drive. Then the inverse of the Rabi frequency tells you how long it takes to completely exchange populations from $|0\rangle \leftrightarrow |1\rangle$, so applying a pulse for half that time will result in a Hadamard gate.